# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a image classifier with a saved model on Flask. 
 Everytime I try to upload an image on my local website, this error pops up in my terminal.

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 
'PIL.Image.Image'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

I assume the 'NoneType' means there is an empty array, hence there is a problem with the image arrays. Correct me if I'm wrong!

If that IS the case, how do I reshape my arrays in this environment?

I have installed Pillow too, so I don't know what data adapter I need to handle `<class 'Pil.Image.Image'>`. It'll be great if I can find the answer to this. 
I am coding in Visual Studio Code.

Here is my full code.

**app.py**

```
from flask import (Flask, request, url_for, redirect, render_template, send_from_directory)
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras 
from PIL import Image
import cv2
from keras.models import load_model 
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
names = {0: 'COVID', 1: 'NORMAL', 2: 'PNEUMONIA'}
model = load_model('./model/covid19.h5')

def predict_label(img_path):   
    res = model.predict(img_path)
    label = np.argmax(res)
    print("Label", label)
    labelName = names[label]
    print("Label name:", labelName)
    return labelName

photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = './static/img'
configure_uploads(app, photos)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return(render_template('main.html'))
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        img_path = image.load_img('./static/img/'+ filename, target_size=None)
        
        #filename.save(img_path)
        p = predict_label(img_path)

    return render_template("main.html", img_path = img_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    
<title>COVID19 DETECTOR</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data action="{{ url_for('main') }}">
    <input type=file name=photo>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<img src="{{img_path}}" height="400px" width="400px">

{% if prediction %}
<img src="{{img_path}}" height="400px" width="400px">
  <h2> Your Prediction   : <i> {{prediction}} </i></h2>

{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

**Traceback**

```
File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)        
  File "C:\Users\Ash\OneDrive\Documents\final year 2nd\fyp\CODING\app.py", line 40, in main
    p = predict_label(img_path)
  File "C:\Users\Ash\OneDrive\Documents\final year 2nd\fyp\CODING\app.py", line 19, in predict_label
    res = model.predict(img_path)
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1608, in predict
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1099, in __init__
    adapter_cls = select_data_adapter(x, y)
  File "c:\users\ash\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 964, in 
select_data_adapter
    _type_name(x), _type_name(y)))
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 
'PIL.Image.Image'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

ps: sorry if I put the questions on a wrong tag. Please be nice

Comment: `ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle`... Please include the full traceback: all the lines before this one, which lead to the exception.  Otherwise people are left guessing where in your code this excepton happened.

Comment: Okay I will add the traceback. Thank you for informing